# How to use matrix variables to conditionally run jobs in a GitHub Actions Workflow

Tags: github-actions

At the time of asking, the `matrix` context is not available in the position of `jobs.<job_id>.if`, as documented [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability).

I want to refactor my workflows, that is, call a reusable workflow conditionally with different parameters, only under certain conditions.

Specifically, I want to build two Docker images (potentially), based on detected changes, conditionally calling the reusable workflow that builds an image; that workflow should not be *aware* of what it is building, just use the parameters, nothing more, nothing less.

The calling workflow is aware of what images to build and essentially performs orchestration.

Answer (score 0):

### State of the Art

Reusable workflows can't be called at the `steps`-level, they must be called at the `jobs`-level, and as stated, the `matrix` context is not available in `jobs.<job_id>.if`.

### Workaround

A workaround, unfortunately, is to always call the reusable workflow, and defer (delegate) the decision to run or not.

This requires a `should-run`-style input parameter, which the reusable workflow should honor, but may decide not to (for reasons of your choice).

The *calling* workflow, triggered on ***push*** or ***pull_request***:
`org/repo/.github/workflows/build_images_orchestration.yaml`

```
name: Build Images Orchestration

on:
  push:
    ...
  pull_request:
    ...

permissions:
  ...

jobs:
  determine-work:
     ...
  call-build-image:
    needs: determine-work
    strategy:
      matrix:
        image: [api, ui]
        include:
          - image: api
            enabled: ${{ needs.determine-work.outputs.build-api }}
          - image: ui
            enabled: ${{ needs.determine-work.outputs.build-ui }}
    uses: org/repo/.github/workflows/build_image.yaml@same-branch
    with:
      # build: ${{ matrix.enabled }} # <--- fails without fromJSON
      build: ${{ fromJSON(matrix.enabled) }}
      image: ${{ matrix.image }}
      tag: ${{ needs.determine-work.outputs.tag }}
    secrets: inherit
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
```

The *called* workflow i.e. triggered by ***workflow_call***:
`org/repo/.github/workflows/build_image.yaml`

```
name: Build Single Image

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      build:
        description: 'Flag whether to build the Image'
        required: true
        type: boolean
      image:
        description: 'Image to build: api or ui'
        required: true
        type: string
      tag:
        description: 'Image tag'
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    if: inputs.build
    ...
```

As indicated, the use of `fromJSON` is necessary where input parameters (to reusable workflows) have type `boolean`; it seems many mechanisms (code paths) in GitHub Actions *silently* coerce values to `string`, which will typically pass a boolean test with *every* non-empty string having a *truthy* value, even `'false'`.

For more information, there is an *extended* conversation on the subject [here](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1483) with this solution originally posted in this [comment](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1483#issuecomment-1708010440)

#### Pro-Tip

Notice how this ensemble also demonstrates how to use `matrix.include` to selectively graft on upstream-outputs to a *matrix-combination*.

The alternative is to use keyed lookups, that is, to string-index into other available contexts e.g. `needs`, `inputs`, etc; for example, in this case, we would drop `matrix.include`s and instead use

```
    uses: org/repo/.github/workflows/build_image.yaml@same-branch
    with:
      build: ${{ fromJSON(needs.build-and-push.outputs[format('build-{0}', matrix.image)]) }}
      ...
```